# Не запускается OpenServer nginx

Tags: nginx, openserver

перешел на Openserver nginx и столкнулся с проблемой то что сервер не запускается

создал `Nginx_1.23_vhost.conf` в корне домена

```
server {
    charset utf-8;
    client_max_body_size 128M;

    listen 80; ## listen for ipv4
    #listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

    server_name api.ping-up.com;

    root        C:/OSPanel/domains/api.ping-up.com;
    index       index.php;

    access_log  /path/to/basic/log/access.log;
    error_log   /path/to/basic/log/error.log;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }
}
```

Comment: Что значит "не запускается", что происходит вместо запуска?

Comment: после запуска он сразу же останавливается

Comment: Ну а в логах хотя бы что-нибудь пишет?

Comment: Не удалось запустить Nginx_1.23 и сбой запуска

Comment: Ну вот значит читайте конкретно логи nginx